# Create an X509Certicate from a DER decoded String

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, x509

I have a X509Certificate  and I write/print it to a file as follows.
(I'm not writing encoded bytes, because I want to read the content of the certicate)

```
X509Certificate cer = generateCertificate(); // cer is DER encoded
writeToFile( cer.toString() ); // cer.toString() converts DER to UTF/ASCII???
```

Later I want to read this file (above) as String and create a new X509Certificate.

```
String cerStr = readCerFromFile(); // Read what is written above. In ASCII/ UTF format
ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
try {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(cerStr.getBytes());
    return (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bais);
} ...
```

This throws following Exception.

```
Java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: Invalid DER-encoded certificate data
```

And it is obvious that I'm not converting cerStr to DER format (and I don't know whether it is possible to convert into DER ). Can any one please explain how can create an X509Certicate from a String which is not encoded.

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: `.toString()` doesn't make any sense. You should write the encoded bytes from `cer.getEncoded()`. Using `X509Certificate.toString` is just shooting yourself in the foot. So don't do that, at least not to persist the certificate.

Comment: Thanx GregS. Is .toString() OK for decoding and printing the DER encoded certificate?

Comment: It is fine for visual inspection of the contents.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer: you cannot. DER encodes too many details that cannot be easily converted to and back from a `String`. You are better off simply saving the DER encoded certificate using `cer.getEncoded()` as GregS has explained in the comments.

If you want to see the the contents of the certificate, simply save it with a file extension that your operating system recognizes and double click it. If you want to have a command line method of printing the plain text information use e.g. openssl:

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -inform DER -in mycertificate.crt
```

Which is standard included or optional in many Unix flavours (Linux, Apple) and can be run on Windows as well.

Comment: You could also create a CLI application within Java of course. Just reading in the cert/decoding it using X509 certificate factory and printing out the cert would be about 10 minutes of work, but then you need to handle installation, shell script creation etc.

Comment: Java keytool might be used as well, it's only available in the SDK though, not the runtime.

Comment: Thanks to @erickson for spell checking this answer, I must have been sleepy.

Answer (score 1):

When you take certificate as raw data `cert.getEncoded()` (in .Net it is `cert.RawData`) it is encoded in DER format. Informally speaking it is just a special binary representation of the certificate.

But there exists good string representation of certificate. You can convert raw representation of certificate in DER to Base64 formatted string. I don't know JAVA, so in .Net it will look like this `Convert.ToBase64dString(cert.RawData)`.

You can save certificate in both formats to a file with **.cer** or **.crt** extension and open it using standart OS certificate viewer.

Answer (score 0):

A poor mans answer (I would very much a lower level)

// create the pfx byte stream...
byte[] selfSigned = CertificateCreator.CreateSelfSignCertificatePfx(distinguishedName,
                                                                    new DateTime(2013, 4, 1),
                                                                    new DateTime(2013, 12, 31),
                                                                    insecurePassword);

// crate a certificate instance
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(selfSigned, insecurePassword);

// export as .cer [DER]
selfSigned = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);

// write to file..
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(certificateFilename+".cer"), selfSigned);

Comment: Thanx David for the answer

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can do

```
    String sCert = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(certificate.getEncoded());
```

In .Net

```
Convert.ToBase64String(Certificate.RawData);
```